# This keyword in C#, Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

What's the meaning of this usage of the `this` keyword in C#:

```
public static ExcelRow Hide(this ExcelRow row)
  {
   return row.Hide(true);
  }
```

Is this Linq ? If yes, what's the difference between `ExcelRow row` and `this ExcelRow row` ?

Note: It's not a spelling bug, there's no point or other accessor in between.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this particular context it denotes that the `Hide` method is an [Extension Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) that can be called on instances of the `ExcelRow` type.

Answer (score 6):

It means that it is an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx). This refers to the instance of ExcelRow for which the method is invoked.

Answer (score 1):

The method you have above is an extension method (msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx). The "this ExcelRow row" part of the signature means that the method extends an excelRow object. So you can use it on an instance of ExcelRow. Eg: ExcelRow row = new ExcelRow(); row.Hide(); The ExcelRow part of the definition (after the static keyword) simply means that your extension method returns an instance of the ExcelRow Type